# Cannot install ROS indigo E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Tags: package-management

I'll try to be as specific as possible (i know little about Ubuntu)
I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit

I really need to install ROS indigo, and I did follow the instructions precisely as shown in: http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu

At the instance:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full

the following error happens: 
E: unable to locate package ros-indigo-desktop-full

But I think I solved with this solution:
http://answers.ros.org/question/188732/e-unable-to-locate-package-ros-indigo-desktop-full/

But then I get the following error (with command):

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-indigo-desktop-full : Depends: ros-indigo-desktop but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-indigo-perception but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-indigo-simulators but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
genoma@genoma-RC530-RC730:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-indigo-desktop-full : Depends: ros-indigo-desktop but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-indigo-perception but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-indigo-simulators but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

It might not be an error, but anyway, it doesn't let me install the packages, and a similar error occurs when i try to install:
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop
```

The dependences increase exponentially!

I've tryed everything I saw similar on the internet, and now i'm asking for help.

(I've tryed also: sudo aptitude install ros-indigo-desktop-full , with no success)

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt install -f`?

Comment: Your non-Ubuntu packages conflict with other packages already installed on your system. You should inform the ROS Indigo upstream project that their non-Ubuntu packages broke your system.

Comment: You may have followed the instructions precisely but you missed the note saying *ROS Indigo **ONLY** supports Saucy (13.10) and Trusty (14.04) for debian packages*... http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#indigo-igloo-may-2014

Comment: For Ubuntu 16.04 you need "Kinetic Kame" or use this: https://github.com/jbohren/rosdocked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I really need the compatibility, and trusty, i went back for Ubuntu 14.04, but it still gave errors until I used this command, I really hope this helps anybody, it solved everything for me.

$ sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-wily